# How to set facebook page order

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook page where I want to add an app as a page. In the old version you could drag'n'drop the tab order, but now I can't find any way to change the order of the pages.

This is my test page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=192515850771209&sk=featured#!/pages/Mtest/192515850771209

The page with the red "M" is my app that I want to be able to set the order where it appears in the list.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

Just under the list is an edit button - click on it - drag and drop in the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the apps and add them back in the order you want them to appear.